# not route found error while creating parameterize restful webservice

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

i am using `symfony 2.2.3` with `FOSRestBundle` to implement `Restful` webservices.

here is my code but when i fire following url i am getting following error

```
No route found for "GET /business/john"
```

here is the controller code

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\Routing\ClassResourceInterface;

class BusinessController extends Controller {


        public function getBusinessAction($para){


          return new JsonResponse(array('name' => $para));
        } 

}
```

here is my url

```
http://localhost/symfony/web/app_dev.php/business/john
```

here is my route

if i remove the argument from url and from function `getBusinessAction` then it works but not with arguments/

```
_business:
    resource: "@HubHomeBundle/Controller/BusinessController.php"    
    type: rest
```

**update**

inside `app/confing/routing.yml`

```
   hub_home:
    resource: "@HubHomeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

Comment: Did you register the bundle routes in app/config/routing.yml?  Also in the terminal type php app/console router:debug. it will list all the routes that are available.

Comment: i have edited the question , but i dont know how to do it with `app/console router:debug`

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure, is this from HubHomeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml?

```
_business:
    resource: "@HubHomeBundle/Controller/BusinessController.php"    
    type: rest
```

If so try editing it and changing it to:

```
_business:
    resource: HubHomeBundle\Controller\BusinessController   
    type: rest
```

The value of your 'resource' tag should be the fully qualified name of the controller Class, not the path to the file

Comment: Go to the root of your project (Where you can see the app, web, config, logs, Resources directories) and run 'php app/console router:debug' whats your output?